# Swift Master Detail View - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

I have been staring at this error and I really cannot figure it out. I feel like everything is done correctly, my labels is attached to my viewController as well but I keep getting this fatal error.

**MasterViewController:**

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = NSMutableArray()
var myBookStore: BookStore = BookStore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myBookStore.theBookStore.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text? = myBookStore.theBookStore[indexPath.row].title
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedBook:Book = myBookStore.theBookStore[indexPath.row]
    if (detailViewController != nil){
        self.detailViewController!.detailItem = selectedBook //send the model to the detailItem
    }
}
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem
    {
        var myBook = detail as Book
        println(titleLabel)
        println(authorLabel)
        println(descriptionTextView)

        println(myBook.title)
        println(myBook.author)
        println(myBook.description)

        titleLabel.text = myBook.title
        authorLabel.text = myBook.author
        descriptionTextView.text = myBook.description
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.configureView()
}
}
```

Println show that:
- titleLabel, authorLabel, descriptionTextView are nil
- myBook.title, myBook.author, myBook.description get correct values as I want

I seen all the same questions but could not find any solution
Please help me. I've started learning Swift for 1 day

Comment: A note: you're printing your objects (`titleLabel`, etc) *before* assigning the text to the label text fields, so of course they seem empty. Solution: make  `println(titleLabel.text)` happen *after* `titleLabel.text = myBook.title`, etc. As for your real problem, you seem to have forgotten to create your model object and to add them to the book store array.

Comment: Thanks but if I delete all println commands, the fatal error still happen. I added println command after see the error to watch out what is happening

Comment: I think the problems didn't come from MasterViewController, because after I click some rows on the list books, the detail informations (title, author, description) passed to DetailViewController. Command "println(myBook.title)" return correct value

Answer (score 0):

The only optional I see is your DetailViewController, which is set to nil at the beginning. I'd guess somewhere in your MasterViewController, you're calling the DVC while it's still nil. Xcode should highlight the light where the error is happening.